# Exclude elements having a parent with a particular class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I do have a script which selects all the tags under a particular element, it also exclude script tags. So right now its as follows.

```
$(myElement).find("*:not(script)").each(function(){
```

But I need to exclude an element and its children. I am not sure how to do it. I tried the following, but it only skips the element with `dontneed` class, not its children.

```
$('body').find("*:not(script):not(:parent.dontneed)")

$('body').find("*:not(script, :parent.dontneed)")
```

Please do help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). That multiple selector should match:

- scripts
- elements that expose the `dontneed` class
- descendants of elements that expose the `dontneed` class.

So you can write:

```
$("body").find(":not(script, .dontneed, .dontneed *)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to

```
$(myElement).find("*:not(script)").filter(function(){
    return $(this).closest('.dontneed').length == 0
})
```

Answer (score 1):

:parent won't do the trick unless it means "element is a parent (has children)"

May be .find() with `*:not(script):not(.dontneed):not(.dontneed > *)`
or `.find('*').not('script, .dontneed, .dontneed > *')`

I prefer second solution.